# Email template text is updated but original is sent

Tags: magento2, admin, magento2.4, email-templates, admin-panel

I am trying to modify the custom email template from admin and send it to customer email.
I logged the template text after I changed it. I wanted to receive an email. I only have a text from the template file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was. Basically in setTemplateIdentifier method of TransportBuilder object argument should be the number not the string.
Number is the ID of admin panel email template.

Hope this helps to someone else.